# how to work around "ValueError: day is out of range for month" with imaginary dates?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib, strptime

ok so I have a list of dates , and i have a list of sales . I want to use matplotlib to plot the values

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dateFormat = findDateFormat()

print dateFormat      #DEBUG#

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,dateFormat).date() for d in listOfDates]
y = listOfSales

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(dateFormat))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

`findDateFormat()` is a function that I created and it return a string that contains the format and i tested it to be okay `%d/%m/%Y`. when I run the script I got the error

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

now I know the reason for that is the dates in the list are not real and some one them do not actually exist (31,6,2016 for example). is there a way to work around this so it just ignores the dates that do not actualy exist?

EDIT
I just created this function:

```
def validateDates(dateFormat):

    itemsToDelete = []

    for i in range(0,len(listOfDates)):
        try:
            dt.datetime.strptime(listOfDates[i], dateFormat)
        except ValueError:
            print listOfDates[i] + "Has been deleted because it does not exist."
            itemsToDelete.append(i)

    for k in range(0,len(itemsToDelete)):
        del listOfDates[itemsToDelete[k]]
        del listOfSales[itemsToDelete[k]]
```

To get rid of non-existent dates before using this in the plot, but I still get same error message.

Comment: Do you want to give those invalid dates a default value, or you just want to ignore those points completely?

Comment: ignored @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just ignore them by this way(`if len(listOfDates) == len(listOfSales)`):

```
from datetime import datetime
x = []
y = []

for d, sale in zip(listOfDates, listOfSales):
    try:
        x.append(datetime.strptime(d, dateFormat).date())
        y.append(sale/10)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

`validateDates` method may as follows:

```
def validateDates(dateFormat, listOfDates, listOfSales):
    dates, sales = [], []    
    for d, s in zip(listOfDates, listOfSales):
        try:
            datetime.strptime(d, dateFormat)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        dates.append(d)
        sales.append(s)
    return dates, sales

listOfDates, listOfSales = validateDates(dateFormat, listOfDates, listOfSales)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you to ignore both dates and sales, you need to pair the two data points together.

Assuming there is a one-to-one correlation (one sale per date), then you can just zip the values and filter out the ones where the date isn't valid.

```
dateFormat = findDateFormat()

def is_valid_date(pair):
   try:
     return (dt.datetime.strptime(pair[0], dateFormat).date(), pair[1])
   except ValueError:
     return None

valid_pairs = filter(is_valid_date, zip(listOfDates, listOfSales))
x = [i[0] for i in valid_pairs]
y = [i[1] for i in valid_pairs]
```

The assumption here is that your dates and your sales are ordered, and there is only one sale figure per date.